# Bad Access on -[NSSet makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:]

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm getting a crash on `[NSSet makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:]` but can't find the place where its happening in my code.
My guess is that it's one of the GestureRecognizers being overreleased, but sadly I can't find anything.

The crashlog:

```
 
Exception Type:
    EXC_BAD_ACCESS
Code:
    KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x3758096392

com.apple.main-thread Crashed
0   libobjc.A.dylib     objc_msgSend + 15
1   CoreFoundation  -[NSSet makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:] + 186
2   UIKit   -[UIGestureRecognizer dealloc] + 124
3   UIKit   -[UILongPressGestureRecognizer dealloc] + 152
4   CoreFoundation  CFRelease + 100
5   CoreFoundation  -[__NSArrayI dealloc] + 78
6   libobjc.A.dylib     (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 168
7   CoreFoundation  _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 16
8   Foundation  __NSFireDelayedPerform + 466
9   CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 14
10  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 272
11  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 1232
12  CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
13  CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
14  GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal + 74
15  UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 1120
16  my.app  main.m line 16 main
```

EDIT: I think I found the problem. I was releasing stuff in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` that some GestureRecognizers depended on.

Comment: I think you're right , you have an object that is being overreleased.
This can be fixed using the 'Zombie' instrument , in simulator. This instrument is not available on the device.

Comment: What is the code that you're using? How are you managing the contents of the set? What else interacts with the contents of the set?

Comment: I'm only calling makeObjectsPerformSelector on 2 places in my code on NSArrays, that's why I'm so clueless. I wasn't able to reproduce the crash so far, the only thing I have right now to search for are the crashreports from different clients.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is doesn't contain enough information to fully explain the problem and solution and is too specific to be of use to further visitors to SO. What we originally would have termed as being "too localised"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem. I was releasing stuff in didReceiveMemoryWarning that some GestureRecognizers depended on.

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint to your project. This should help home in on the problem.

Comment: I did, but I wasn't able to reproduce the problem. I had to rely on crashreports.